# Is this possible to define the continuous map from equivalent class?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, equivalence-relations

Let $M$ be a compact metric space and $f: M \rightarrow M$ be a quotient map.

Consider the following equivalent relation $\sim$ such that $x_1\sim x_2 \Leftrightarrow f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ for a given quotient map $f$.

We know that $f$ is closed map. Hence, there exists a homeomorphism $\tilde{f}:M/\sim \rightarrow M$ by $\tilde{f}([x])=f(x)$, where $[x]=\{x' \mid f(x)=f(x')\}$ is equivalence class.

Now I am curious about this part.

Can we define a continuous function $\alpha:M/\sim \rightarrow M$ such that $\alpha([x])=x' \in [x]$ ?

Comment: Questions, questions, ... : what is $M$, what is the topology on $M$, what is $x'$ ,....

Comment: Don't you mean a homeomorphism $M/\sim\to K$ where $f:M\to K$?

Comment: What is x' and why does not the homeomorphism answer your question?

Comment: Thank all of you for yours comments. I editted my question. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $[x]$ has at least two elements then $\alpha([x])=x'\in[x]$ would depend on the choice of $x'$. In other words $\alpha$ **is not** well defined in general.

But the definition $\tilde f([x]) = f(x')$ for $x'\in[x]$ **is** correct. It **doesn't** depend on the choice of $x'\in[x]$, because for any $x_1, x_2\in[x]$ we have $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ by the definition of $\sim$.

The question about the continuity of $\tilde f$ is a whole different story though and requires a proof. But it's a more general fact:

> Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a quotient map. Define a relation on $X$ by $x\sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$. Then there's a well defined homeomorphism $F:X/\sim \to Y$ given by $F([x])=f(x)$.

Note that $X, Y$ don't have to be compact, metric or equal and $f$ does not have to be closed.

Comment: In this case, $\alpha$ is a function which extracts elements one by one from equivalent class. So $\alpha$ is a well-defined function.
I am just able to define $\alpha$ so that it is continuous

Comment: @TrầnLinh Functions don't "extract" anything. And especially not "one by one" (whatever that means). Functions (being a specific subset of a Cartesian product) either are well defined or not. $\alpha$ is not correctly defined. Let's say that you have a set $X=\{1,2\}$ and define a relation on $X$ such that $1\sim 2$. Now $X'=X/\sim$ is a simply a singleton, $X' =\{X\}$. It has exactly *1 element*. Now you want to define a function $\alpha:X'\to X$ and you say $\alpha(X)=x'\in X$. So what is $\alpha(X)$? Is it $1$ or $2$? You have to decide, there is no such thing as "one by one extraction".

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it.